# Navigation Bar Navigation Items causing top area of buttons on pushed view controller to not be tappable

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a strong feeling that this might be a bug with Xcode that apple just needs to fix.  I have a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller as the root controller.  The view controller has a button that is vertically aligned with the top layout guide. The view controller's button works fine and all of the tappable area is working.

[image]

However, if I push the same or a similar view controller on to the navigation stack, it's button will not be completely tappable.  The top of the button (about 10 pixels or so) is no longer tappable.  If I try to tap at the top left of the button, the back button on the navigation bar is tapped instead, even though I am clearly not tapping the navigation bar bounds.  I assume this is a bug with apple but I was wondering if anyone knows of a fix. Here is the [link to the github project](https://github.com/kyzer1978/NavigationBarTest) if anyone needs it.

Comment: If you can have your button a little bit more height, it could be tabbed, or you can tabbed a little bit lower than the title of the button

Comment: I actually tried doing that.  It didn't completely work because there was still a few pixels that are still covered at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior for iOS. Many `UIView`s have this extended touch functionality in iOS. For example, `UINavigationBar`, `UITabBar`, `UISecgmentedControl` etc. I believe this is to make easer touch to these controls.

If you still want to override this default behavior. You can do this by subclassing `UINavigationBar` and add this method in the subclass:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

A merge request to your [Github project](https://github.com/rishi420/NavigationBarTest) is made.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a swift version of the solution in case anyone needs it:

```
class CustomNavBar: UINavigationBar {

  override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
      userInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
      userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    return super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
  }
}
```

**Swift 3** and higher:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = self.point(inside: point, with: event)
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```